# Test class for Http Request

Tags: unit-test, class, http

I need test class for the below class i have for code coverage. Please help.

class and its code is

```
public CodeCoverageController(){
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        Http httpObj = new Http();
        request.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+ApexClassorTriggerId,ApexClassorTrigger.Name,ApexClassorTrigger.Type,LastModifiedBy.Name,LastModifiedDate,NumLinesCovered,NumLinesUncovered,Coverage+FROM+ApexCodeCoverageAggregate+ORDER+BY+NumLinesCovered+ASC');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response = httpObj.send(request);
        String responseReq = response.getBody();
        deserializeResponse jsonResponse = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(responseReq, deserializeResponse.class);
        copyJsonResponse = jsonResponse;

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        http h = new http();
        req.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+PercentCovered+FROM+ApexOrgWideCoverage');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res = h.send(req);
        String responseReqObj = res.getBody();
        deserializeResponse responseObj = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(responseReqObj, deserializeResponse.class);
        totalCodeCoverage = responseObj.records[0].PercentCovered;
    }
```

Comment: In general, you should make a good faith effort before posting here. Just asking *"How do I write a test for this class?"* is almost always going to be negatively received. Instead, explain what you have tried so far and where specifically you are stuck. If you get an error message, include it verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize a Mock class to provide a response to the HTTP callout, which cannot be executed in test context.

You should read through [Testing HTTP Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing.htm) and consider completing [Apex REST Callouts](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts) on Trailhead to design a test class that can achieve full coverage using an `HTTPCalloutMock`.